# regex() and regcmp() functions not in LINUX

Tags: linux, unix

I'am porting pro*c codes from UNIX to LINUX.  In one of the application codes,  regex() and regcmp() functions are called.  These functions am not finding in LINUX.  Also there regexec() and recomp() functions in LINUX but these are not the same as regex() and recmp().  Any help on this??

Comment: also ligen.a library is not there in linux. is there any package where libgen.a can be installed or any equivalent functions/library?

Answer (score 3):

The standard C library provides `regcomp` and `regexec`, which are probably what you're looking for.  See the `regex` man page (type `man 3 regex`).

There are alternative regular expression implementations out there that may be more featureful, such as [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) (which may already be available on your system).

Comment: regcomp and regexec prototypes are different from regcmp() and regexec().  pls refer http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/3c/regcmp/ for solaris regcmp().

Comment: You may want to update your question to make it clear exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: my questiong is clear.  i want to know Linux equivalent functions for UNIX functions regex() and regcmp().  and linux equivalent library for unix library libgen.a

Comment: there are no regex() and regcmp() in linux.  i modified code to use regexec() and regcomp() and compiled.  Not sure it will work on runtime.